# audit2allow for unix socket on android gives blank output

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I have an app that connects to my socket server running within mediaserver (in my audio HAL)

SElinux throws this log when connecting (from dmesg):

```
[  251.022149] type=1400 audit(1491810054.932:24): avc: denied { connectto } for pid=9065 comm="com.gps.app1" path=0073727663 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
```

I tried feeding it to audit2allow to get te file, but it returns a blank rule:

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ audit2allow -i ~/gps-ott/selinux/denied.txt -m appcon

module appcon 1.0;



gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$
```

Can someone point me to what I did wrong, or what te file could be used to allow this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you supply the compiled sepolicy from 'out'?
You should.

```
audit2allow -p ./out/target/product/<your-device>/root/sepolicy
```

Comment: what do you mean `sepolicy from 'out'? `

Comment: One of the products of android boot.img compilation is a 'sepolicy' file. This is the file

Comment: oh, hmm I'm only asking as I'm getting the same issue but on RHEL for nginx, but I'm not sure if the cause is the same issue as the audit is showing `res=success` for nginx` despite nginx getting access denied for the puma socket.

Answer (score 0):

First, your binary file out/target/product//root/sepolicy must exist.

After this:

1- to clean dmesg buffer, launch the command:

```
sudo dmesg -c
```

2- launch your app which creates the interesting dmesg line (i.e. "[  251.022149] type=1400 audit(1491810054.932:24): avc: denied { connectto } for pid=...")

After this, localize the good 'audit2allow' script (don't use the /usr/bin/audit2allow one but the one coming with your AOSP installation e.g. external/selinux/prebuilts/bin/audit2allow)

Then, launch from the PC on which the AOSP is installed after launching the classic 'adb connect >targeted_device_@ip<

```
adb shell su root dmesg | ./external/selinux/prebuilts/bin/audit2allow -p out/target/product/<your_product_name>/root/sepolicy
```

this command will provide to you the good SEpolicy rules to create your own .te SEpolicy file.